Is there a way to show slide indicator and autoplay CarouselView in Flutter 3.24?
Is there a way to autoplay the items in CarouselView?
CarouselView(
     elevation: 2,
     itemSnapping: true,
     itemExtent: 330,
     shrinkExtent: 100, 
     children: [
       _CardLayout(index: 1, label: "assets/images/image1.jpg",color: Colors.blue),
       _CardLayout(index: 2, label: "assets/images/image2.jpg",color: Colors.green),
       _CardLayout(index: 3, label: "assets/images/image3.jpg",color: Colors.red),
     ])

I've tried checking the options of CarouselView and seems theres no available properties like showing slide indicator and autoplay like the one in flutter_carousel_widget
Thanks in advance.

there is no direct way but you can write your own custom logic using the controller here. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CarouselController-class.html

There isn't a straightforward option to autoplay the items in the new CarouselView widget. However, you can achieve this functionality by controlling the CarouselController manually. Here’s an example:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final Timer _timer;
  late final CarouselController _carouselController;

  final _itemExtent = 330.0;
  final _autoPlayDuration = const Duration(seconds: 4);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _carouselController = CarouselController();

    // Animates to the next item every 4 seconds
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      _autoPlayDuration,
      (_) => _animateToNextItem(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _carouselController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _animateToNextItem() {
    _carouselController.animateTo(
      _carouselController.offset + _itemExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.linear,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: CarouselView(
          elevation: 2,
          itemSnapping: true,
          shrinkExtent: 100,
          itemExtent: _itemExtent,
          controller: _carouselController,
          children: List.generate(
            10,
            (index) => Container(
              color: index.isOdd ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In this example, a Timer is used to automatically move to the next item every 4 seconds by adjusting the CarouselController. This mimics an autoplay behavior. The animation duration and curve can be customized as needed.


Hmm I see. My missing piece is that Timer.periodic and the proper usage carouselController.animateTo( ) to move to the exact next item. Thanks for this.
